# Where is the overflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the following code, I want the div named "buttons_wrapper" to scrolling when the size of the screen is smaller than all elements of the page, but doesn't work. I have an almost the same page but it works perfectly. What's the wrong with it?

Sorry for my bad english.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: #bfbfbf;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #buttons_wrapper{
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 25px 0 25px 0;
            width: 100%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        #ad_banner{
            position: fixed;
            overflow: hidden;
            bottom: 0;
        }

        .top_bot_space{
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .my-btn{ 
            background-color: #000;
            color: #00FFF6;
            border-color: #00FFF6;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .my-btn:hover{
            background-color: #000;
            color: #F82F5F;
            border-color: #F82F5F;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div id="buttons_wrapper">
        <div class='container text-center top_bot_space'>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2">
                <a id="website" href="#" class="btn my-btn btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-globe"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;webpage</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='container text-center top_bot_space'>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2">
                <a id="website" href="#" class="btn my-btn btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-globe"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;webpage</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='container text-center top_bot_space'>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2">
                <a id="website" href="#" class="btn my-btn btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-globe"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;webpage</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='container text-center top_bot_space'>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2">
                <a id="website" href="#" class="btn my-btn btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-globe"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;webpage</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='container text-center top_bot_space'>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2">
                <a id="website" href="#" class="btn my-btn btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-globe"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;webpage</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='container text-center top_bot_space'>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2">
                <a id="website" href="#" class="btn my-btn btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-globe"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;webpage</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ad_banner">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="somescript.js"></script>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var body_height = $("body").outerHeight();
        var logo_height = $("#logo").outerHeight();
        var ad_banner_height = $("#ad_banner").outerHeight();
        var buttons_wrapper_height = body_height - logo_height - ad_banner_height;
        $("#buttons_wrapper").css("height", buttons_wrapper_height + "px");
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: "... but doesn't work." isn't very helpful. Please fully describe your problem and your debugging attempts

Comment: There is no scroll-bar at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Based on your additional explanation, a viewport-based height needs to be set on `<body>`, to avoid the `body` height being determined by its content. Like so:

```
body { height: 100vh; }
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2owzfrk/1/)

**Original Answer**

The issue seems to be with vertical scroll, because you currently have `overflow: hidden` set on your `<body>`. So on a phone with a shorter screen, you wouldn't be able to scroll down. Change that to `overflow-x: hidden` if you'd like to keep preventing horizontal scroll, and you should be good.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2owzfrk/)

Comment: But I don't want to scroll the whole page. I need scrolling only #buttons_wrapper. If I remove overflow: hidden from body, then the scroll-bar appears for the whole document.

Comment: OK, makes sense. Then I think the issue is that the height of your `<body>` isn't limited by the height of your viewport, and is instead based on your content. So the value of `body_height` in your function isn't changing with shorter viewports. You can set your `<body>` to always match the viewport with `vh`; try adding `height: 100vh;` to `body`. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2owzfrk/1/). Will edit the answer if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Oh!!!!! You are right! I forgot to set body height. I set it as 100%. Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool, glad to help :)